# Bash SyntaxError in node module (Angular clone)

Tags: angular, windows, bash, ng

I have cloned an Angular project and got the following error message

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run start


> clone-side@0.0.0 start
> node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/ng serve

E:\me\Projekt\cloneFe\node_modules\.bin\ng:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.16.1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

my ng file lookks like this.

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*|*MINGW*|*MSYS*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  exec "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../@angular/cli/bin/ng" "$@"
else
  exec node  "$basedir/../@angular/cli/bin/ng" "$@"
fi
```

i'm Running that on IntelliJ ultimate in Windows

I have tried another "node" version with vola but
the error remains constant regardless of the setup.

Especially since it's a bash error, I don't know if node.js plays a role at all.
Here is the comparison in a self-made angular project of the ng file

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*|*MINGW*|*MSYS*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  exec "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../@angular/cli/bin/ng.js" "$@"
else 
  exec node  "$basedir/../@angular/cli/bin/ng.js" "$@"
fi
```

Comment: The error message obviously is not issued by bash, as you can see for example from the backtrace.

Comment: Don't run from your node modules, run `npx ng serve` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Nested executions is a bad idea in bash (mix of `$(...)` and also nested `"..."`).

Try to replace:

```bash
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
```

with:

```bash
slash_progname=$(echo -n "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')
basedir=$(dirname "$slash_progname")
```

You also could replace echo + sed with:

```bash
slash_progname="${0//\\//}"
```

So, the line should be:

```bash
basedir=$(dirname "${0//\\//}")
```

And finally:

```bash
slash_progname="${0//\\//}"
basedir="${slash_progname%/*}"
```